# WinUI 3: How to bind to data itself in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, winui-3

Consider a ListView:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind People}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate x:DataType="models:Person">
    <controls:PersonItem Person="{...}" />
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In this case, `People` is a property of type `ObservebleCollection<Person>` defined in code-behind. The class `Person` is defined like:

```cs
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }

  // The implemention of INotifyPropertyChanged:
  ...
}
```

The control `PersonItem` is a custom user control with defined `DependencyProperty` which is called `Person` and receive a `Person` object as value. This control will use the member of this property to display some information on the screen.

**What I want to know is that how could I bind `Person` attribute to the data itself in the
data template, in other words, what should be used to replace the `...` in the first code snippet?**

Although I know that properties in `Person` is so few that I could simply define each of them as `DependencyProperty` in my custom control, but the actual situation I encountered is that I got a class which has too many properties need to be used in one control, then the work I need to do will be too much.

Comment: I've already tried: `x:Bind`, `Binding`, `Binding Path=.` and `Binding Path=/`, but all of them have no effect so I could only get `null` which is the default value of dependency property `Person`.

Comment: PersonItem might be setting its own DataContext, which would at least break `Person="{Binding}"`.

Comment: @Clemens How could I know if it set its own DataContext? Could you explain more about this? I have no idea about the mechanism behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `x:Bind` or `Binding` should work.

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3App;

public sealed class PersonItem : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Person),
            typeof(Person),
            typeof(PersonItem),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPersonPropertyChanged));

    public PersonItem()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PersonItem);
    }

    public Person Person
    {
        get => (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty);
        set => SetValue(PersonProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnPersonPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is Person person)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WinUI3App;

public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            People.Add(new Person()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3App"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind People}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                <!--<local:PersonItem Person="{Binding}" />-->
                <local:PersonItem Person="{x:Bind}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I believe that I just did the same with you, but because of some reason it didn't work. Do you know how to debug this code? Could it be because I bind items source to a static object? But the `ListView` rendered two objects which means there 
should be something in items source. Strange.

Comment: I actually created a sample app for this and works (OnPersonPropertyChanged() receives a ``Person`` instance). Can you try the exact code in my answer?

Comment: It seems like data binding is succeed but `GetValue()` always return `null`...

Comment: Your Person ``DepndencyProperty`` is working. You just need to add ``Mode=OneWay`` to both ``x:Bind``s inside your UserControl. I know it's confusing but ``x:Bind`` is ``Mode=OneTime`` by default.

Comment: Wow. Good spot Andrew. What a strange design decision. "The binding object can optionally be configured to observe changes in the value of the data source property and refresh itself based on those changes"

Comment: It finally works. Thanks! I have considered that may be I need to set `Mode` but I just thought `OneWay` should not be the problem. I have never thought about that the default `Mode` is `OneTime`.

Comment: @AkiraVoid But keep in mind, only for `x:Bind`. The default Binding Mode for `Binding` depends on the target property, but is usually `OneWay`.

Comment: @Clemens yes and that's why I'm misdirected.

Comment: @Andy ``OneTime`` is the default mode on ``x:Bind`` for performance enhancements. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#:~:text=%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20has,part%20of%20the%20binding.).